# How to properly use OpenMP?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I'm building a program that should multiplicate two matrices. The question is, I should do it using OpenMP parallelization but on just one "for" loop each time (first the outsider loop, then its child and then the inner loop) and, for each parallelization method, I should analyze the result when using different quantity of threads (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128).

My question is, where should I put the OpenMP parallel/private sections and what variables should be private/shared to accomplish this ?

```
// code to be parallelized using n_threads
omp_set_dynamic(0);     // Explicitly disable dynamic teams
omp_set_num_threads(n_threads);


#pragma omp parallel for shared(a, b, c) private(i,j)
for (i=0; i < TAM_MATRIZ; i++){
  for (j=0; j < TAM_MATRIZ; j++) {
    c[i][j] = 0; // initialize the result matrix with zeros
    for (k=0; k < TAM_MATRIZ; k++){
      #pragma omp atomic
      c[i][j] +=  a[i][k]*b[k][j];
    }
  }
  printf("Number of threads used: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads()); 
}
```

**EDIT**

In fact, it's three programs, the first one parallelizing just the outsider loop, the second one just the middle loop and the last one parallelizing the inner loop.
Each version should run 8 times, using the specified threads (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128), and then we should compare the performance against the different program versions and same versions using different thread numbers.

My doubt sits where to share or make private it variable. When parallelizing first loop, what variables should be shared ? And when I'm working on the second loop, what variables are shared ? etc...

In my mind, I can't share any variable because I'll have multiple threads working on same time and can make partial results, but I know I'm wrong and I'm asking here basically to understand why .

Comment: You can actually exam or reuse the http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/. It can accelerate by GPU i.e. OpenCL or CUDA, or OpenMP.

Comment: Thank you for the response Victor Gubin !
In fact, it's just an exercise from my college's subject. The purpose here is to learn how to use OpenMP and apply it on a simple code example.

Comment: @AndréRocha (badly) parallelizing the middle or inner loop changes nothing about the data sharing advice in my answer. The only issue is that you must add back the atomic (or a clever reduction) if you parallelize the innermost loop (of the `ijk`-loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track - this is actually quite simple.

- You missed `k` in your `private` clause - this would lead to issues as it is by default `shared` when defined outside. Instead of explicitly choosing the data sharing for each variable, the best way is to declare variables as locally as possible (e.g. `for (int ...)`, this will almost always be desired and it's easier to reason about. `a`, `b`, `c`, come from the outside and are implicitly `shared` - the loop variables are declared inside and implicitly `private`.
- Fortunately there is no need for the `#pragma omp atomic`. Each thread works on a different `i` - so no two threads could ever try to update the same `c[i][j]`. Removing the `atomic` will greatly improve performance. If you ever need atomic, also consider reduction as an alternative.
- If you want to print `omp_get_num_threads`, you should do it outside of the loop, but inside the parallel region. In your case this means you have to split `omp parallel for` into a `omp parallel` and `omp for`. Use `omp single` to make sure only one thread outputs.

Be aware that very good performance from a matrix multiplication is much more complicated and beyond the scope of this question.

**Edit:**

For nested loops it is generally better to parallelize the outermost loop if possible - i.e. no data dependency that prevents it. There can be cases where the outermost loop does not yield enough parallelism - in those cases you would rather use `collapse(2)` to parallelize the outer 2 loops. Do not use `(parallel) for` twice unless you absolutely know what you are doing. The reason for this is that parallelizing the middle loop yields more smaller pieces of work which increases the relative overhead.

In your specific case one can safely assume `TAM_MATRIZ >> n_threads`<sup>0</sup>, which means the outermost loop has enough parallel work for all threads to be used efficiently.

To reiterate the data-sharing rules. For a normal `parallel` region.

- Variables defined inside the lexical scope of a `parallel` region (and parallel loop variables) are implicitly private. Those are variables your threads work on. If a variable is only used within a lexical scope, always<sup>1</sup> define it in the narrow-most possible lexical scope.
- Variables defined outside of the lexical scope are implicitly shared by default. Those are variables are typically input/output to the parallel region - so it has to be shared. Make sure to avoid data races.

If you follow this, there is almost never a need to explicitly define the `private`/`shared` data-sharing attributes<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>0</sup> Otherwise it wouldn't even make sense to use OpenMP here.

<sup>1</sup> Exceptions apply for non-trivial C++ types with expensive ctors.

<sup>2</sup> `reduction` / `firstprivate` are useful to be used explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Zulan.
Ok, I got it ! But I still have doubts when thinking abou the other ways to parallelize it. I mean, to do it just on the outsider loop I should do as you mentioned but what about parallelizing just the middle loop ? 
How do I know what variables are shared and what are privates ? Where do  I tell OpenMP that it's a shared region ?

Comment: @AndréRocha I edited the answer to clarify this. Note: there is no such thing as a *"shared region"* only *shared variables*.

Comment: I added an answer based on swapping the loops over `j` and `k`. As far as I can tell you would not want to use `collapse(2)` in my case. In your case `collapse(2)` could be appropriate. What do you think?

Comment: I have been thinking about row-major order vs column-major order and dependency chains since this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133851/2542702. Using column-major order for matrix*vector breaks the dependency chain so although you have to do the work sharing over the inner loop (which adds some overhead compared to doing it over the outer loop) it has the advantage of breaking the chain which I explain in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320608/2542702.

Comment: @Zboson I agree with the collapse and your swapping suggestion. I wouldn't use `collapse(2)` simply because it should not be necessary. I had hoped that the compiler could actually swap the loops but from a quick glance it doesn't seem to be the case. In any case my answer focuses on the OpenMP aspect since the performance aspect for matrix multiplication is so vastly open-ended.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers.
I guess I made a mistake when I explained myself, I'll edit my question to fix it.
But you've opened my mind when using OpenMP anyway, thank you !

Comment: @Zulan, yeah you answer the OPs question better than mine so I did not try and duplicate your answer. Swapping the loops and breaking the dependency is the easiest optimization than can be done though it does not fix the problem that it's still memory bandwidth bound unless you use loop tiling.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider swapping the order of the `j` and `k` loops like this

```
memset(c, 0, sizeof(c[0][0])*TAM_MATRIZ*TAM_MATRIZ);
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < TAM_MATRIZ; i++)
for (int k=0; k < TAM_MATRIZ; k++)
for (int j=0; j < TAM_MATRIZ; j++)
  c[i][j] +=  a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```

That will likely have more of a performance benefit than parallelization because it makes much better usage of the cache. But it also has an additional benefit which is more subtle: it removes the dependency chain on the summation.

Floating point mathematic is not associative which means that (a + b) +c is not necessarily equal to a + (b + c).  When your inner loop goes over `k` then each iteration it writes to the same variable `c[i][j]`. If you change the order you do the summation (e.g. with SIMD) then you may get a different result. Without OpenMP or a looser floating point model, e.g. with `-Ofast`, your compiler (except for ICC which by default allows associative floating point arithmetic) will likely not even use SIMD when there is a dependency for floating point.

However, when the inner loop is over `j` each iteration `c[i][j]` writes to a different element so the dependency is broken. Breaking the dependency not only gives you consistent results independent of the number of threads or SIMD width it improves performance due to better cache usage and also allows SIMD even with a strict floating point model.

Comment: Thank you @Z boson.
But if I change the order of i and j loops it will give me bad calculations or I'll just invert the calculation order (column coming first than lines) ?

Comment: @AndréRocha if you swap the order of `i` and `j` (`i` being the inner most loop) then your code will get the correct answer but be very slow as it won't read/write to consecutive memory address but will have a large stride between each read/write.